# Is there a standard notation for nested factors?

Tags: modeling, notation

What is the standard notation for specifying nested factors, for example, if I am estimating a parameter $\large{\beta{{_\text{site}}_i}}$ for the effect of $i=1\ldots m$ sites, and $\large{\beta{{_\text{tr}}_j}}$ for $j=1\ldots n$ treatments, assuming that there are no treatments that occur at each site (except the control, in which case $\beta{_\text{tr}}=0$, how would I note that any given treatment $j$ is associated with one and only one site?

Here is one representation of my model:

$\large{\Theta_{k} = \beta{_0} + \beta_{\text{site}_{i}} + \beta_{\text{tr}_{ij}}+ \epsilon}$

But I am not sure that simply indexing $ij$ gets this point across, or does it?

Some sources seem to use $\large{\beta_{\text{tr}_{ij}}}$ while others use $\large{\beta_{\text{tr}_{j(i)}}}$.

Comment: Since a treatment is unique to each site can't you just use `i` to index both?

Comment: @AndyW there can be one or more treatments per site

Comment: I don't think there really is a standard notation.  Having said that, Andrew Gelman uses $\beta_{\text{site}}$ and $\gamma_{\text{treat[site]}}$; I like this notation because it reduces the depth of subscripts and makes clear that $\gamma$ varies across treatments that are linked to sites.

Comment: @jbowman can you provide a reference to Gelman's use of the $\gamma_{\textrm{treat}[\textrm{site}}]$ notation?

Comment: Sure, Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models. http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Regression-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Analytical/dp/0521867061)

Comment: @jbowman thanks. it is on my shelf. Skimming through it, there are many different options, none seem "standard", most seem intuitive, although I would like to avoid using superscripts (e.g. p 302-303).

Comment: Yes, I agree, there aren't any standard ones; this just happens to be one I like.  I'm looking at the example on page 2 and the overview of hierarchical models on p. 237, by the way.

Comment: @jbowman it seems he would either put the names as superscripts or use $\alpha,\beta$ to distinguish parameters. I like the superscript. Rather than move this to a discussion, you could copy-paste our discussion here into an answer, (feel free to lift my points too), and then we can delete the comments.